# How can I turn on File and Printer sharing, and the Firewall from the Windows command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, remote-access

I am using PsExec to access cmd on a Windows 7 computer on my network, and I want to turn on `File and Printer Sharing`, followed by the Windows firewall without having to get up and walk all the way to the computer.

What commands do I need to use to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I thought psexec required file and print sharing before it would remotely connect.  How can you remotely enable it, if you can't connect to remotely enable it?

Comment: The Firewall is currently off

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This command should take care of the File and Printer Sharing:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=Yes
```

For the firewall:

```
netsh advfirewall set currentprofile state on
```

I've tried them just now, and its seems to work for me.

For any additional information see Microsofts KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709

Comment: Thanks for the KB link for netsh advfirewall. That's handy.

Answer (score 1):

To turn on file and printer sharing only for private profile one can use this command:

`netsh firewall set service type=fileandprint mode=enable profile=standard`

For Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 and later OS one can use other command:

`wmic /namespace:\\Root\StandardCimv2 path MSFT_NetFirewallRule where (RuleGroup="@FirewallAPI.dll,-28502" and Profiles=2) call enable`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `net start` command to start a service. For example:

```
net start "Windows Firewall"
```

From my limited investigation, though, File and Printer Sharing is not a service invokable by name at a CLI. Windows Firewall is, however.

Answer (score -1):

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="File and Printer Sharing (SMB-In)" dir=in new enable=Yes
```

see here:  https://serverfault.com/a/739272/83850

Comment: (1) Thank you for providing a link to a page where a similar question is discussed, but it looks like [SU] had it first.   (2) Can you explain how this answer differs from the accepted answer?

Comment: (1) the link has more information (2) This command specifies direction